# Database model design for single entry transaction between two accounts?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I am building an app that helps people transfer money from one account to another. I have two tables "Users" and "Transactions". The way I am currently handling transfers is by

1. Check if the sender has enough balance to make a transfer.
2. Deduct the balance from the sender and update the sender's balance.
3. Add the amount deducted from the sender's account to the recipient's account and then update the balance of the recipient.
4. Then finally write the transaction record on the "Transactions" table as a single entry like below:

```
id | transactionId | senderAccount | recipientAccount | Amount |
—--+---------------+---------------+------------------+--------+
 1 | ijiej33       |      A        |         B        |   100  |
```

so my question is, is recording a transaction as a single entry like above a good practice or will this kind of database model design produce future challenges?

Thanks

Comment: As long as you don't COMMIT the transaction until all 4 steps have completed, then yes, your transaction row format is fine.  You probably should have a transaction timestamp as well.

Comment: for sure there is a commit and rollback transaction + timestamps. I just removed it for simplicity just for the question.

Comment: You need to consider [transaction isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html) levels, too.

Answer (score 3):

> Check if the sender has enough balance to make a transfer.
>
> Deduct the balance from the sender and update the sender's balance.

Yes, but.

If two concurrent connections attempt to deduct money from the sender at the same time, they may both successfully check that there is enough money for **each** transaction on its own, then succeed even though the balance is insufficient for **both** transactions to succeed.

You must use a SELECT FOR UPDATE when checking. This will lock the row for the duration of the transaction (until COMMIT or ROLLBACK), and any concurrent connection attempting to also SELECT FOR UPDATE on the same row will have to wait.

Presumably the receiver account can always receive money, so there is no need to lock it explicitly, but the UPDATE will lock it anyway. And locks must always be acquired in the same order or you will get deadlocks.

For example if a transatcion locks rows 1 then 2, while another locks rows 2 then 1: the first one will lock 1, the second will lock 2, then the first will try to lock 2 but it is already locked, and the second will try to lock 1 but it is also already locked by the other transaction. Both transactions will wait for each other forever until the deadlock detector nukes one of them.

One simple way to dodge this is to use ORDER BY:

```
SELECT ... FROM users WHERE user_id IN (sender_id,receiver_id) 
ORDER BY user_id FOR UPDATE;
```

This will lock both rows in the order of their user_ids, which will always be the same.

Then you can do the rest of the procedure.

Since it is always a good idea to hold locks for the shortest amount of time, I'd recommend to put the whole thing inside a plpgsql stored procedure, **including the COMMIT/ROLLBACK** and error handling. Try to make the stored procedure failsafe and atomic.

Note, for security purposes, you should:

Store the balance of both accounts before the money transfer occured into the transactions table. You're already SELECT'ing it in the SELECT for update, might as well use it. It will be useful for auditing.

For security, if a user gets their password stolen there's not much you can do, but if your application gets hacked it would be nice if the hacker was not able to issue global UPDATEs to all the account balances, mess with the audit tables, etc. This means you need to read up on this and create several postgres users/roles with suitable permissions for backup, web application, etc. Some tables and especially the transactions table should have all UPDATE privileges revoked, and INSERT allowed only for the transactions stored procs, for example. The aim is to make the audit tables impossible to modify, basically append-only from the point of view of the application code.

Likewise you can handle updates to balance via stored procedures and forbid the web application role from messing with it. You could even add take a user-specific security token passed as a parameter to the stored proc, to authenticate the app user to the database, so the database only allows transfers from the account of the user who is logged in, not just any user.

Basically if it involves money, then it involves legislation, and you have to think about how not to go to jail when your web app gets hacked.